# Using Monolog within Doctrine document into SF2 applications

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm, monolog

Since you can't inject SF2 services into a Doctrine document, how do you write a log (using monolog) from a document?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because I need to log some kind of business logic (yeah, I know and agree, it shouldn't occur there) executed into the document.

Comment: what kind of business logic? like logging changes on entities/documents? The only changes you might want to log are ones being persisted to your database afterwards ... those can be logged in a Listener. There is normally no need to have the logger available in your entity.